# In Playframework 2.1.x how to select the native coffescript in development mode only

Tags: heroku, playframework, coffeescript, playframework-2.1

In Play 2.1.x and higher you can use native coffeescript compilation by adding to Build.scala  a directive like:

```
coffeescriptOptions := Seq("native", "/opt/local/bin/coffee -p")
```

This is a very nice improvement on speed but it breaks when the coffee binary is not present, e.g. when deploying to heroku.

Can you set that option in development mode only? That way I can get the speed for development and in production is a one time cost.

It seems that Build.scala does not have yet the information if we are in production or development mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but you might want to try using [Multi Buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to combine the [Node.js Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) and the [Scala Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala). The Node.js buildpack should let you bring in Coffee Script binary and then the Scala buildpack would do the Play build.

To get started, you'd do this:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git

$ cat .buildpacks
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```

and then you'd need add a `package.json` that brings in the `coffee-script` dependency:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

You would also need to update your `/opt/local/bin/coffee` path to where NPM drops the binary. It likely be at `$HOME/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee`.

Comment: I tried this and seems to go well until I get an error [error] (*:play-copy-assets) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "$HOME/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory. I commented out the settings in Build.scala and I can see the buildpack did install coffeescript at the right place

Comment: Since this failure is happening at build time, try using `$BUILD_DIR` instead of `$HOME`. If this is also needed at runtime, you might need to do a little hack to set `BUILD_DIR` to `/app` with `heroku config:add BUILD_DIR=/app` so it can find it at runtime too. Another thing to look at is if SBT allows env vars to be used directly inline like that in Build.scala.